# Rss reader in PHP

Tags: php, rss

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
 $tmpFile = 'tmpFile.txt';

 $val="http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/topstories";
  $curlHandle = curl_init($val);  
 $filePointer = fopen($tmpFile, "w");  
 curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_FILE, $filePointer);  
 curl_exec($curlHandle);
 curl_close($curlHandle);
 fclose($filePointer); 

 $linesArr = file($tmpFile);  
 foreach($linesArr as $eachLine){
 echo($eachLine);
}
```

The program supposed to fetch all the materials from yahoo rss sites and output them into the tmpFile.

After executed the program, I opened up the tmpFile.txt.  It shows

c1.ops.sp1.yahoo.com uncompressed/chunked Wed Apr 11 01:46:41 UTC 2012 -->

This doesn't look right.   I pasted the url http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/topstories there are plenty of materials returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you needed was `curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");` .... `yahoo` uses `compression` for its `rss` feed ...

Additional Information Include .

A. `CURLOPT_USERAGENT`.... Its nice if you don;t what to start looking like spam

B. `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`... Just for effeciency

C. `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` .. Becasue of issues with clean URL and routes

Working Code

```
header ( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
$tmpFile = 'out.txt';

$val = "http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/topstories";
$curlHandle = curl_init ( $val );
$filePointer = fopen ( $tmpFile, "w" );
curl_setopt ( $curlHandle, CURLOPT_FILE, $filePointer );
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.342.3 Safari/533.2');
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,5);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_exec ( $curlHandle );
curl_close ( $curlHandle );
fclose ( $filePointer );

$linesArr = file ( $tmpFile );
foreach ( $linesArr as $eachLine ) {
    echo ($eachLine);
}
```

I hope this helps .. let me know if you need anything more

Comment: And _what did you change_?? Please don't dump out "try this code" answers. Annotate them to say what's different and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `http` wrapper support with file_*_contents:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$tmpFile = 'out.txt';
$content = file_get_contents("http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/topstories");
file_put_contents($tmpFile, $content);

echo $content;
```