# xml data return from PHP to JQuery can't catch

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xml, rss

according to this suggestion:
[Rss Reader in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099062/rss-reader-in-php)

I have changed my bridge.php

```
<?php
header ( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
$tmpFile = 'out.txt';
$val = "http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/topstories";
$curlHandle = curl_init ( $val );
$filePointer = fopen ( $tmpFile, "w" );
curl_setopt ( $curlHandle, CURLOPT_FILE, $filePointer );
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US)    AppleWebKit/533.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.342.3 Safari/533.2');
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,5);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_exec ( $curlHandle );
curl_close ( $curlHandle );
fclose ( $filePointer );
$linesArr = file ( $tmpFile );
foreach ( $linesArr as $eachLine ) {
echo ($eachLine);
}
?>
```

A "out.txt" create successfully:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Yahoo News - Top Stories</title>
<link>http://news.yahoo.com/topstories/</link>
<description/>
<language>en-US</language>
<copyright>Copyright (c) 2014 Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved</copyright>
<pubDate>Wed, 07 May 2014 22:54:13 -0400</pubDate>
<ttl>5</ttl>
<image>
<title>Yahoo News - Top Stories</title>
<link>http://news.yahoo.com/topstories/</link>
...
</rss>
<!-- fe927.global.media.sg3.yahoo.com compressed/chunked Thu May  8 03:00:48 UTC 2014 -->
```

I omit the content body of the rss feed because of post word number limitation. Anyway, the "bridge.php" seems to work well.

But in my JQuery script I can't successfully catch the return xml content.

```
      $.ajax({type: "GET", dataType: "xml", url: 'bridge.php', success: handler, error: error_handler});
  return false; 
}

function error_handler(xhr, status, error) {
alert("error");
}
```

Neither success nor error handler in this .ajax() call can execute. To debug I put `.ajax(dataType:"text")` and put some debug code in data.php, it works to catch the correct information from PHP to JQuery.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Check the response in the Developer Tools of your browser. If it is correct but not recognized as XML, try sending the Content-Type header.

Comment: If you want a simple working solution without the need to build a backend (with your bridge.php, check this solution: http://blog.superfeedr.com/jquery-superfeedr/)